# Are there any online tools to test android-wear app which tells if the app is missing out anything related to design guidelines?

Tags: wear-os, sony-smartwatch

I'm building my new android-wear app and I have followed my android-wear guidelines as per [Android-Wear guideline](https://developer.android.com/training/wearables/apps/debugging.html#wifi-debugging), but my app was getting rejected my google android-wear team in-spite of building as per guideline. I would like to know if there is any other alternate tools to test my android-wear app or community people who can test my app and let me know what am I missing so that I can fix and make it accepted in android-wear category by google.

Answer (score 2):

You may check this [Launch checklist](https://developer.android.com/distribute/best-practices/launch/launch-checklist.html). This checklist brings together the processes you should follow to ensure your app is launched successfully. The tasks are numbered to give you an idea of the normal sequence in which they would be actioned. However, you can handle the tasks in any sequence that works for you and skip steps as appropriate.

Also, your Wear apps should be designed to perform well and look great on Android Wear, and they should offer the best user experience possible. Google Play will showcase selected high-quality Wear apps for easy discovery. [Here’s how you can participate and deliver an Android Wear app that users will enjoy](https://developer.android.com/distribute/best-practices/launch/distribute-wear.html#test_app):

- Meet the core app quality guidelines

  - Follow [Android Design guidelines](https://developer.android.com/design/index.html). Pay special attention to using [Material Design](https://material.io/guidelines/material-design/introduction.html) in your app.
  - Test your apps against the [core app quality](https://developer.android.com/develop/quality-guidelines/core-app-quality.html) guidelines.
- Meet the Wear app quality guidelines:

  - Follow the best practices for [Wear app development](https://developer.android.com/training/building-wearables.html).
  - Make sure your app meets all of the [Wear app quality](https://developer.android.com/develop/quality-guidelines/wear-app-quality.html) guidelines.

Comment: Thanks I have gone through all these guidelines and compared my app with these guidelines. Its fine but as per the app functionality I don't have any interaction from my watch to phone. All  I have done is to notification in my watch for the user and watch uses the sensors to monitor and get the data and this data is sent to phone. 

I mailed back to google team the same explaining why we did not have interaction of phone and watch like replying back from watch to phone.